# Nuxt 3 layers does not work correctly when accessing project page from another project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

How to make a project run independently and also access via layers and run? Currently, I have a project which looks like this:

```
root
 ┣ commons
 ┗ project1
 ┗ project2
```

I am using the commons in both `project1` and `project2` by using in respective `nuxt.config.js`:

```
extends: ["../commons"]
```

and within my `project1 nuxt.config.js` I am using both `commons` and `project2` as I need to navigate to some pages in `project2` from `project1`:

```
extends: ["../commons", "../project2"],
```

I want my `project2` to run independently as well as it should work when I navigate from `project1` to `project2`. When I am running independently `project2` it works fine but when I navigate to a page from `project1` I see that some of the values are not imported correctly such as `locales` and certain component imports are not working correctly.

I found that when I access from `project1` the components in `project2` try to look into `project1` components instead of `project2` due to this some of the components are not loaded.

How to handle this scenario and ensure that the `project2` works independently as well as from `project1`

Comment: Face similar problem, wish there are more help on the Nuxt extends feature. Does not seem to be fully functional as described.

Comment: @IvanLim Actually in my case I was able to make it work by adding something like this:

`
  // auto import components
  components: [
    {
      path: "~/components",
      pathPrefix: false,
    },
    {
      path: "../project2/components",
      pathPrefix: false,
    },
  ],

extends: ["../common", "../project2"],
`

Comment: I haven't tried specifying the `components` key, I could try that. In my case though the components were imported successfully. It would fail only if the extended project used a library that was not available in the core project (e.g. `nuxt-viewport`). Had to manually add the library to the core project, then it worked. Not efficient though, have to remember to remove the library from the core if the extended project is no longer needed, should be handled by the extend feature itself IMO.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make it work like this:

```
  // auto import components
  components: [
    {
      path: "~/components",
      pathPrefix: false,
    },
    {
      path: "../project2/components",
      pathPrefix: false,
    },
  ],

extends: ["../common", "../project2"],
```